# why we cannot access the method via object with :: in perl

Tags: perl, class, object

I wrote the `Perl module`, In that I use the `class and objects`.
So I create the object for the class and access its methods.
For example:

```
{
    package sample;
    sub Bless 
    {
        my $Class = shift;
        my $Name = shift;
        bless \$Name, $Class;
    }
}
{
package test;
        our @ISA = qw(sample);
    sub Print 
    {
        my $Name = shift;
            print "Hi, I'm $$Name & This is for testing\n";
    }
}

my $My_Obj = test->Bless('Ganapathy');
$My_Obj->Print;
```

For the above statement, The program has running properly.
When I executed it it gives the output like this,

```
Hi, I'm Ganapathy & This is for testing
```

But if I access the method using the object with `::` like this,

```
 $My_Obj::Print;
```

It has not working and it throw the error like below,

```
Useless use of a variable in void context at /home/ganapathy/trainee_2015/perl/inter_perl/chap_13/Object_Doubt.pl line 46.
Name "My_Obj::Print" used only once: possible typo at /home/ganapathy/trainee_2015/perl/inter_perl/chap_13/Object_Doubt.pl line 46.
```

why I can't access like that, Please any one help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In `$My_Obj::Print` you are asking for the scalar variable `Print` from the package `My_Obj`

You haven't assigned to it or used its value, so basically you're just mentioning the name of a scalar variable, and you get the message

> Useless use of a variable in void context

What is it that you're trying to do? `$My_Obj` is clearly an object, and you have had success calling it's `Print` method using `$My_Obj->Print`. Why do you want to do it in a different way?

Comment: @Ganapathy: It *is working*. `->` and `::` are very different things and aren't interchangeable.